# Outlook - Calendar groups missing after new profile

Tags: office365, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016

A user had set up lots of calendar groups in his Outlook 2016, connected to an Office365 mailbox.

During maintenance his local Outlook profile was deleted and a new one was created and now all of these custom calendar groups are now missing.

The question is, are these Calendar Groups stored in his actual mailbox? Or locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested in my environment and the Calendar Groups synced normally. So the Calendar Groups shoud be stored in the server. Please try exiting Outlook desktop client and see if you can find your Calendar Groups on the web mail. If the Calendar Groups displayed in your web mail, then it is suggested to click "Send/Recieve" > "Update Folder".

Comment: As suspected. My further question is then, could it be that this particular user has Office2016 installed (from when his mailbox was on-premise) and that his Outlook 2016 tries to sync to the on-premise Exchange server? While the actual content is on 365?

Comment: The data of Office 365 account is stored in the server, not related to the version of the Outlook client or Exchange.